# :app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease error: Unstripped native library path required by generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease does not exist:

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I'm using firebase crashlytics gradle plugin 2.4.1. I build a CMake c library in an android library that the App depends on. The App's `build.gradle` contains this:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
                unstrippedNativeLibsDir "build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/"
                strippedNativeLibsDir "build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/release/out/lib/"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when running `:app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease` I get this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease'.
> Unstripped native library path required by generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease does not exist: /Users/nick/Documents/project/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib. Check your configuration, or override using the firebaseCrashlytics.unstrippedNativeLibsDir extension property.

However:

```
ls /Users/nick/Documents/project/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib
arm64-v8a       armeabi-v7a     mips            mips64          x86             x86_64
```

Is this a bug with the plugin or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am dealing with this error, too. It appears to me like bug in the `generateCrashlyticsSymbolFile..` task. It looks like build types are mixed up. Have you tried to run `assembleDebug` and `assembleRelease` at the same time? I noticed that the Firebase task will then generate the `*.cSYM` files. This is not a solution but maybe a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using cmake then correct paths should be as follows:

```
strippedNativeLibsDir './build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/release/out/lib'
unstrippedNativeLibsDir './build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj'
```

Comment: I am using cmake, but in a library. So in the app, the libraries are in the paths in the original question

Comment: use path to library then. "../lib/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj"
I also have lib+app setup and when I used path as yours "build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/" I got the same error. with my path everyhting is works fine.